# R: color certain cells in Matrix

Tags: r, lattice

I am wondering whether I can color only certain cells in an R matrix using the

```
image
```

command. Currently, I am doing this:

```
library(Matrix)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

csv_name <- args[1]
pdf_name <- args[2]

pdf(pdf_name)
data <- scan(csv_name, sep=",")
len <- length(data)
num <- sqrt(len)
matrix <- Matrix(data, nrow=num, ncol=num)
image(matrix)
dev.off()
```

The CSV file contains values between 0 and 1. 
Executing the above code gives me the following image:

[image: Matrix visulization]

Now, I want to color in each row the six smallest values red.
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, 
Sven

Comment: Do you mean "row" of the matrix or "row" in the image? From `?image`: "the x axis corresponds to row number and the y axis to column number ... i.e. a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation"

Comment: This is essentially the same. In my CSV file, I have N rows of N numbers, which will displayed in the file by an NxN matrix.

Comment: Ach, sorry. `Matrix`, not `matrix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix seems to use lattice (levelplot). You can add a layer on top,

```
m = Matrix(1:9, 3)
library(latticeExtra)
image(m) + layer(panel.levelplot(1:2,1:2,1:2,1:2, col.regions="red"))
```

Edit: actually, it makes more sense to give the colors in the first place,

```
levelplot(as.matrix(m), col.regions=c(rep("red", 6), "blue", "green", "yellow"), at=1:9)
```

but I haven't succeeded with image:

```
image(m, col.regions = c(rep("red", 6), "blue", "green", "yellow"), at=1:9)
```

I may have missed a fine point in the docs...

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply make another matrix where all values are NaN and then add a value of 1 to those that you want to highlight:

```
set.seed(1)
z <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10,10)
image(z)

z2 <- z*NaN
z2[order(z)[1:5]] <- 1
image(z2, add=TRUE, col=4)
```